# AJAX returning false but I don't understand why?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to do a database query for a keyword on input change instantly. Right now, I get a successfully query, with all the results stored, but on the `GET` to display them my `ajax` function returns false. Why does it do that?

Console output:

```
POST http://example.com/functions/ajax.php

response: the data i need to display
```

followed by a

```
GET http://example.com/functions/ajax.php

response: false
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#url').bind('input', function () {
        $(this).val() // get  value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'functions/ajax.php',
            data: {
                url: $('#url').val()
            },
            success: function (data) //on receive of reply
            {
                $(function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'functions/ajax.php', //the script to call to get data          
                        data: "", //you can insert url arguments here to pass to api.php
                        //for example "id=5&parent=6"
                        dataType: 'json', //data format      
                        success: function (data) //on receive of reply
                        {
                            var namePHP = data[1];
                            var categoryPHP = data[2];

                            //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                            // 3) Update html content
                            //--------------------------------------------------------------------

                            $('#name').html(namePHP); // # name and #category are input fields I want autofilled
                            $('#category').html(categoryPHP);


                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once ('DBconnect.php');

$url = $_POST['url'];

$url = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $url);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `inserted_posts` WHERE `search_name` = '$url'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing an AJAX call to the same page in the callback of the AJAX call?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Why not? Different method, parameters and datatype :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to auto fill input bars with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199886/want-to-auto-fill-input-bars-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ajax.php` file relies on `$_POST` variables. This means you MUST send data with using the `POST` method. Otherwise, PHP just doesn't see it.

Comment: It recives the data, and it sends a response back via POST, the problem lies in inserting the data in to the input feilds

Comment: Sorry, sends the response with 

echo json_encode($array);

and i can see the response in the console

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable assignment for $url to pull from $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
```

to

```
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
```