# Want to auto fill input bars with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i want to auto fill some input bars using AJAX, i have a small issue

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url">

<input type="text" name="name" id="name">

<input type="text" name="catagory" id="catagory">
```

so, when url is filled, this javascript is run

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#url').bind('input', function () {
        $(this).val() // get  value
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'functions/ajax.php',
            data: {
                url: $('#url').val()
            },
            success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
            {
                $(function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'functions/ajax.php', 
                        data: "",
                        dataType: 'json', //data format      
                        success: function (data) //on recieve of reply
                        {
                            var namePHP = data[1]; 
                            var catagoryPHP = data[3];

                            $('#name').html(namePHP);
                            $('#catagory').html(catagoryPHP);

                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

According to the console, i get 2 responses on a valid keystroke, i get a POST which responds with my data, and i get a GET which returns false???

my ajax.php is here if you want to look at that

```
<?php
require_once ('DBconnect.php');

$url = $_REQUEST['url'];

$url = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $url);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `inserted_posts` WHERE `search_name` = '$url'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I get the data back that i need, but it is not inserted in to the input feilds?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the contents of an input, rg

```
$('#name').val(namePHP);
```

Also you aren't sending any data in your second ajax request

Comment: the second response, the GET, still returns false, and feilds are not filled out with the data

Comment: Well, can i do it all in one request?

Comment: @JohnDoe what is the purpose of the second request?

Comment: To edit the HTML feilds with the $array that is echoed back, but i guess the array is echoed in the first request, and the second one is empty .. just realised this

I am sorry, i am fairly new to AJAX

Comment: Can i send the $url get the feedback and edit the HTML in 1 request?